# Getting type cast issue when adding up the values from an array (array_agg)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I was trying to sum up all the values from an array in PostgreSQL, tried different way but always getting the issue `function sum(numeric[]) does not exist`. Even I have tried with casting, but still that shows the same issue. Am I missing anything here?.

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(items)) FROM (SELECT SUM(p.total_price) FROM (SELECT 
ARRAY_AGG(cart_items.unit_price) FILTER (where cart_items.type = 2) AS total_price 
from cart inner join cart_items on cart_items.cart_id = cart.id where cart.id = 
40868884) AS p) AS items;
```

Result is:

```
                                          array_to_json                                          
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[{"total_price":[1.867,1.867,1.867,1.867,1.867,1.21,1.867,1.867,1.56,1.867,1.867,1.867,44]}]
```

Basically, I want to sum up these values of the column prices after taking it from the database.

**Fiddle**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3fdd3/4

Comment: Can you set up a db<>fiddle?  Your query has no `sum()` so that seems like a strange error to be getting.

Comment: Actually I had put the correct statement, now I have updated with the SUM, @GordonLinoff

Comment: I have added fiddle @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want to do is sum up the prices in your json `"totalprice"` fields, then you can use:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(price)
        from (select json_array_elements_text(j.el->'total_price')::numeric as price
              from json_array_elements(t.x) j(el)
             ) j
       )
from (select '[{"total_price":[1.867,1.867,1.867,1.867,1.867,1.21,1.867,1.867,1.56,1.867,1.867,1.867,44]}]'::json as x) t
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon, thanks for the this, actually I cannot put this in my query as the actual query is big, so I just have take some portion and put it here to find the part, is there anyway I can simplify with the existing query?

Comment: @Developer . . . You can wrap your query in a CTE and then use this code in the outer query.